# NullPointerException on TextInputLayout

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, butterknife

I'm new to Android dev and I'm trying to run a legacy app. Now I'm facing a problem with TextInputLayout. I have the following code:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Bind(R.id.login_input_user)
TextInputLayout login_input_user;

@Bind(R.id.login_input_password)
TextInputLayout login_input_password;

@Bind(R.id.login_bt_enter)
Button login_bt_enter;

@Bind(R.id.login_version)
TextView login_version;

private String username;
private String password;
private Context mContext;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    mContext = getApplicationContext();

    LoginServices.invalidateAccessToken();

    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    initViews();
}

private void initViews() {
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        username = "test";
        password = "test";

        if (login_input_user.getEditText() != null)
            login_input_user.getEditText().setText(username);

        if (login_input_password.getEditText() != null)
            login_input_password.getEditText().setText(password);
    } else if (login_input_user.getEditText() != null) {
        login_input_user.getEditText().setText(LoginServices.getCurrentLogin());
        username = LoginServices.getCurrentLogin();
    }
    new BindValue(login_input_user).setBind(value -> username = value.toString());
    new BindValue(login_input_password).setBind(value -> password = value.toString());

    login_bt_enter.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        Device.hideSoftKeyboard(LoginActivity.this);

        if (isValidLogin()) {
            if (Device.hasNetwork()) {
                doLogin();
            } else {
                CustomAlert.showAlertMessage(LoginActivity.this, R.string.alerta_error, R.string.message_no_network);
            }
        } else {
            CustomAlert.showAlertMessage(LoginActivity.this, R.string.alerta_error, R.string.login_error);
        }
    });

    login_version.setText(String.format(getString(R.string.login_version_text), BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE, BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME));
}
}
```

This is my activity_login.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/windowLoginBackground"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/login_logo"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/login_logo_contentdescription"
        android:scaleType="fitEnd"
        android:src="@mipmap/app_logo" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/login_input_user"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/login_lb_user"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/login_input_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/login_lb_password"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login_bt_enter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:text="@string/login_bt_enter"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/login_version"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:text="Versão: 1.0.0" />
```

When I hit initViews and get this line `if (login_input_user.getEditText() != null)` I get a NullPointerException. Looks like login_input_user is null.

Where can I initiate this?

This code has been already built and distributed some time ago. They used a previous version of Android Studio and I had to upgrade it to 3.0 and it's plugins to necessary versions to run. So this code once worked fine.

Comment: Add `activity_login.xml` to the question

Comment: please paste your xml file here.

Comment: Did the id correct?

Comment: I edited the post with the xml file

Comment: please check my ans

Comment: @RenanVasconcelos I think you have a problem with `ButterKnife`. Maybe I'm wrong but I didn' see before keyword `Bind` which version of `ButterKnife` you are using. I used `ButterKnife` couple times. There is just `BindView`. Try to upgrade your `ButterKnife` to `9.0.0-snapshot` or downgrade it on `8.4.0` which also works with Android Studio 3.0.

Comment: I'm using 7.0.1. I'll try to update it.

Comment: Upgrade it on `8.4.0` and change `Bind` to `BindView`. Also make sure you upgrade all on `8.4.0`: `butterknife`, `annotationProcessor` and `gradle plugin`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure is it helps, but I can't comment questions yet.

Try to check which version of Butterknife you are using.
If you also updated the libs version it may break it.

After 8 version, annotations was changed.

> @Bind becomes @BindView and @BindViews (one view and multiple views,
>   respectively).

https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: Updated Butterknife but got the same problem.

Comment: To be sure. Now you have:
 
`dependencies {  
  compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'  
  annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'  
}`

and all of your views annotated with `@BindView(...)`?

Comment: I was using 8.4.0 and not using annotationProcessor. My bad! You, sir, saved my day! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (login_input_user.getEditText().toString() != null)
```

OR

```
if(login_input_user.getEditText().toString().trim().length() == 0)
```